# Using an accessor or mutator if the column has 2 consecutive underscores

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a column in my database `Started_Trading__c`. I'm struggling to use an accessor for this field. So far I have tried the following with no luck.

`public function getStartedTrading_cAttribute()`

`public function getStartedTrading__cAttribute()`

`public function getStarted_Trading__cAttribute()`

`public function getStarted_Trading_cAttribute()`

What would be a valid way to get an accessor working with this type of column name which has 2 consecutive underscores `__c`.

Unfortunately I have no control over the database column names so ideally i'd like to get this to work.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `getStartedTradingCAttribute`

Comment: @N69S to be fair, surely this means Laravel is indifferent about the underscores? You should add this as an answer.

Comment: @JesseOrange here is complete answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel uses the `Str::class` to process strings, for the name of the mutator it uses the method `camel`.

The following strings will all result in `getStartedTradingCAttribute`

```php
Str::camel('get started trading c attribute')
Str::camel('get started_trading_c attribute')
Str::camel('           get started___trading__________c attribute')
Str::camel('get____started  __  trading   __c  ___attribute')
```

The method you need to declare is `getStartedTradingCAttribute()`

For more details (methods are simplyfied)

```php
public static function camel($value)
{
    return lcfirst(static::studly($value));
}

public static function studly($value)
{
    $key = $value;

    $value = ucwords(str_replace(['-', '_'], ' ', $value));

    return str_replace(' ', '', $value);
}
```

As you can see, all `_`(underscore) are replaced with  (space) then nothing in `studly()`